# Как раскрасить вывод telnet прямо в консоли?

Tags: linux, telnet

Задача - покрасить некоторые слова и регулярные выражения в выводе `telnet`.
Попробовал `GRC` - он парсит построчно, а `telnet` выводит посимвольно, немного помогло вывод через `stdbuf`, но всё равно выходит коряво, да и меньше одного килобайта `stdbuf` не обрабатывает, да и сам `GRC` портит разметку.

Еще пробовал Rainbow тут уже было лучше, но проблема всплыла в другом, когда например в сеансе который запущен с использование `rainbow` нажимаешь стрелку вверх (для выбора предыдущей команды), то она обрабатывается как `"^[[A"` так-же не работает `TAB` и тому подобное.

Как думаете это вообще реально реализовать? Что-бы и функции клавиш нормально срабатывали и вывод раскрашивался?

Возможно, например, подправить этот `rainbow`, что-бы норм было, или в питоне это не получится?

Answer (score 1):

> Что-бы и функции клавиш нормально срабатывали и вывод раскрашивался?

Когда мне надо было "красить" вывод в консоли telnet, и использовал управляющие последовательности, описанные в

[Управляющие последовательности ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI#cite_note-6)

Comment: Имеется ввиду то что уже выведено, я выступаю только клиентом

Comment: Я правильно понял - Вы хотите ввести в командной строке нечто вроде *telnet | colourise* где *colourise* -некий фильтр, перехватывающий вывод *telnet* и "красящий" некоторые его части ?

Comment: Да, именно так!

Comment: А тогда причём тут "стрелка вверх"? Ведь такой фильтр будет обрабатывать только  stdout... Или Вы хотите и свой ввод тоже раскрашивать ?

Comment: Так вот и казалось бы, что так должно быть, но по идее, если мы вводим команду
rainbow telnet localhost
то телнет запускается через программу rainbow и клавиши передаются конкретно в неё, и по всей видимости она не прозрачно передаёт их дальше, или кстати может она их вообще не передаёт дальше... сейчас попробую посмотреть, хотя конечно я в питоне вообще не алё :)

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю, что за программа rainbow  и как она работает. С моей точки зрения, самый простой способ - вывод телнета, через канал, соединить с чем-то вроде sed, а в его управляющем файле записать команды замены ключевых слов на те же ключевые слова, но в окружении кодов цвета.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас потыкаю. По описанию выглядит похожим на то, что нужно!